# Class variable doesn't work properly as I want with overloaded operator=

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operator-overloading

Maybe I am missing something, but for some reason an overloaded `operator=` can successfully work with the `Fuel` variable but not with `Capacity`, even though they have the exact same attributes.

```cpp
class CGasStation
{
private:
    int Capacity[4];
    int Fuel[4];
    int PistolSize;
public:
    CGasStation(int StartingFuel = 100, int StartingCapacity = 200, int StartingPistolSize = 10);
    virtual ~CGasStation();
    void SetCapacity(int NewCapacity, int StorageNum);
    void SetPistolSize(int);
    void AddFuel(int, int StorageNum);
    float FuelUpCar(float, int StorageNum);
    void FixFuel();
    void FixCapacity();
    void GetInfo(int StorageNum);
    /*__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________*/
    CGasStation& operator= (const CGasStation & NewSize);
    /*__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________*/
    CGasStation& operator= (const CGasStation & NewSize);
```

```cpp
#include "GasStation.h" 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
CGasStation::CGasStation(int StartingFuel, int StartingCapacity, int StartingPistolSize)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    {
        Capacity[i] = StartingCapacity;
        Fuel[i] = StartingFuel;
    }
    PistolSize = StartingPistolSize;
}
void CGasStation::FixFuel()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (Fuel[i] > Capacity[i])
        {
            Fuel[i] = Capacity[i];
        }
    }
}
void CGasStation::FixCapacity()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (Capacity[i] < 50)
        {
            Capacity[i] = 50;
        }
    }
}
CGasStation::~CGasStation()
{
}
void CGasStation::GetInfo(int StorageNum)
{
    cout << "Capacity: " << Capacity[StorageNum] << endl << "Fuel: " << Fuel[StorageNum] << endl << "Pistol Size: " << PistolSize << endl << "________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;
}
void CGasStation::SetCapacity(int NewCapacity, int StorageNum)
{
    Capacity[StorageNum] = NewCapacity;
    if (Capacity[StorageNum] < 50)
    {
        Capacity[StorageNum] = 50;
    }
}
void CGasStation::SetPistolSize(int NewPistolSize)
{
    PistolSize = NewPistolSize;
    if (PistolSize < 10)
    {
        PistolSize = 10;
    }
    if (PistolSize > 300)
    {
        PistolSize = 300;
    }
}
void CGasStation::AddFuel(int AdditionalFuel, int StorageNum)
{
    if (AdditionalFuel < 0)
    {
        AdditionalFuel = 0;
    }
    Fuel[StorageNum] = Fuel[StorageNum] + AdditionalFuel;

}
float CGasStation::FuelUpCar(float SoldFuel, int StorageNum)
{
    if (SoldFuel < 0)
    {
        SoldFuel = 0;
    }
    if (SoldFuel > Fuel[StorageNum])
    {
        SoldFuel = Fuel[StorageNum];
    }
    Fuel[StorageNum] -= SoldFuel;
    return (SoldFuel / PistolSize);
}

/*__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________*/
CGasStation& CGasStation::operator= (const CGasStation& NewSize)
{
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Capacity[i] = NewSize.Capacity[i];
            Fuel[i] = NewSize.Fuel[i];
        }
    return *this;
}
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "GasStation.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    CGasStation GasStation;

    int choise, StorageNum, a, b;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Menu:" << endl << "1-Get information" << endl << "2-Change capacity" << endl << "3-Change pistol size" << endl << "4-Add fuel to the storage" << endl << "5-Fuel up a car" << endl << "6-Exit" << endl << "7-Set new capacity and fuel amount for all storages" << endl << "8-increase cacity and fuel amount for all storages" << endl << endl;
        cin >> choise;
        cout << "________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;
        if (choise != 1 && choise != 2 && choise != 3 && choise != 4 && choise != 5 && choise != 6 && choise != 7 && choise != 8)
        {
            cout << "Pomilka";
            break;
        }
        
        if (choise == 1)
        {
            cout << "Which storage would you like to check?(1-4)" << endl;
            cin >> StorageNum;
            cout << endl;
            if (StorageNum != 1 && StorageNum != 2 && StorageNum != 3 && StorageNum != 4)
            {
                cout << "Pomilka";
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                GasStation.GetInfo(StorageNum - 1);
            }
        }
        if (choise == 2)
        {
            cout << "Which storage would you like to change in size?(1-4)" << endl;
            cin >> StorageNum;
            cout << endl;
            if (StorageNum != 1 && StorageNum != 2 && StorageNum != 3 && StorageNum != 4)
            {
                cout << "Pomilka";
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Insert new size value (cannot be less than 50)" << endl;
                cin >> a;
                cout << endl << "________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;
                GasStation.SetCapacity(a, StorageNum - 1);
                GasStation.FixFuel();
            }
        }
        if (choise == 3)
        {
            cout << "Insert new pistol size value (10<your size<300)" << endl;
            cin >> a;
            cout << endl << "________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;
            GasStation.SetPistolSize(a);
        }
        if (choise == 4)
        {
            cout << "Which storage would you like to fill up?(1-4)" << endl;
            cin >> StorageNum;
            cout << endl;
            if (StorageNum != 1 && StorageNum != 2 && StorageNum != 3 && StorageNum != 4)
            {
                cout << "Pomilka";
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "How much fuel would you like to add?" << endl;
                cin >> a;
                cout << endl << "________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;
                GasStation.AddFuel(a, StorageNum - 1);
                GasStation.FixFuel();
            }

        }
        if (choise == 5)
        {
            cout << "Which storage would you like to use for filling?(1-4)" << endl;
            cin >> StorageNum;
            cout << endl;
            if (StorageNum != 1 && StorageNum != 2 && StorageNum != 3 && StorageNum != 4)
            {
                cout << "Pomilka";
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "How much would you like to use up?" << endl;
                cin >> a;
                cout << endl;
                cout << "Time to fill up a car: " << GasStation.FuelUpCar(a, StorageNum - 1) << " minutes" << endl << "________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;

            }

        }
        if (choise == 6)
        {
            break;


        if (choise == 7)
        {
            cout << "What capacity and fuel amount would you like to set?" << endl << endl;
            cin >> b;
            GasStation = b;
            GasStation.FixCapacity();
            GasStation.FixFuel();
            cout << "________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;
        }
   }
    return 0;

}
```

Changed it to show the entire program, as this is a university project that is requiring me to use the previous project, so everything made before must be kept as it is, and the only part I can change is overloading. And yes, I must overload it, I can't just say that it's fine without it.

Here's a screanshot of the result:

[image]

Starting amount for `Capacity` is 200, and starting amount for `Fuel` is 100. In the screanshot, `Fuel` changed just as the program intended, its just that `FixFuel` got into the work of making sure it doesn't go past the limit, but `Capacity` didn't change at all, and I don't know why.

I have no idea what's wrong, and this is my first question on this website, so I hope some of you can help me out.

Here's a really short version of the same problem:

```cpp
class Testing
{
private:
    int a[4];
    int b[4];

public:
    Testing(int startingA = 100, int startingB = 200);
    void GetInfo(int Number);
    /*__________________________________________________*/
    Testing& operator= (const Testing& NewNum);
};
```

```cpp
#include "Testing.h" 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
Testing::Testing(int startingA, int startingB) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    {
        a[i] = startingA;
        b[i] = startingB;
    }
}
void Testing::GetInfo(int Number)
{
    cout << "a: " << a[Number] << endl << "b: " << b[Number] << endl << endl;
}
Testing& Testing::operator= (const Testing& NewNum)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        a[i] = NewNum.a[i];
        b[i] = NewNum.b[i];
    }
    return *this;
}
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Testing.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Testing Test;

    int choise, Number, NewNum;
    while (true) 
    {
        cout << "Menu:" << endl << "1-Get info" << endl << "2-Change info" << endl << "3-exit" << endl << endl;
        cin >> choise;
        if (choise != 1 && choise != 2 && choise != 3) 
        {
            cout << "error";
            break;
        }
        if (choise == 1) 
        {
            cout << endl << "Which number would you like to check?(1-4)" << endl << endl;
            cin >> Number;
            cout << endl;
            if (Number != 1 && Number != 2 && Number != 3 && Number != 4)
            {
                cout << "error";
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Test.GetInfo(Number - 1);
            }
        }
        if (choise == 2) 
        {
            cout << endl << "Imput new number" << endl << endl;
            cin >> NewNum;
            Test = NewNum;
            cout << endl;
        }
        if (choise == 3)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Test results]

The question is, why does value `a` change, but value `b` doesn't? How do I fix that?

Comment: Have a look at how to make a [mcve]. Specifically the **minimal** part. *I have no idea whats wrong* Just dumping all your code here and leaving a vague reference to `operator=` being an issue... where? Show a clear, **short** code example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: There is no need to overload `operator =` for your `CGasStation` class.  All of the member variables are safely copyable as-is.  You're introducing problems that need not be introduced.  You totally left out `PistolSize` in your version of the copy constructor.  If you had not written one, the compiler would have provided the default `operator=`, *and would have done so without error, all working, and efficient*.

Comment: `CGasStation& CGasStation::operator= (const CGasStation& NewSize)` -- This function is already provided by the compiler.  Totally remove your version (meaning get rid of both the declaration and the definition), and in addition, remove the empty destructor.  Then retest your code.

Comment: this is a uni project, its specified to take previous project and add overload operators, pistol size is ignored because i already did everything what i wanted with it in other methods, i will try to make a new project and test everything there. (and ye i cant realy dump it because as i said i must use this example) i will also change it to show the entire program not just the part i am having trouble with.

Comment: @CookieB1t "*pistol size is ignored because I already did everything what I wanted with it in other methods*" - it does not make sense to implement an assignment operator that does not assign *every* data member. If assigning a `CGasStation` object of different pistol size should not alter the `PistolSize` of the destination object then it shouldn't be a data member to begin with.

Comment: @CookieB1t -- *i already did everything what i wanted with it in other methods* -- A assignment operator is supposed to copy everything, not make partial copies.  Please note that an assignment operator will be called *by the compiler without you knowing it's being called*.  So you can't write code like this -- the purpose of the assignment operator is to make a copy -- nothing more, nothing less.  Adding side effects as you're doing is wrong and leads to bugs, just like the bugs you're seeing now.  You now have two or more copies of `CGasStation` with conflicting `PistolSize` values.

Comment: And note, bugs like this are some of the hardest to diagnose and to find.  When fundamental functions that C++ uses like assignment and copy do not do their job correctly, all sorts of things get weird and or break down.